# How to get BuildingElementProxys of ifc-files?

Tags: python, ifc, bim, ifc-open-shell

I have to extract some convection coolers out of an ifc-file. They're saved as BildingElementProxys & are in relation with IfcRelContainedInSpatialStructure.
My approach is to get all the IfcRelContainedInSpatialStructures & search with a for-loop through the RelatedObjects if there are objects which are also an IfcBuildingElementProxy.
But I'm not which excact commands I got to use for the for-loop.
Would be great if someone could help

That's what I've got so far:

```
import ifcopenshell
import ifcopenshell.util
from ifcopenshell.util.selector import Selector
import ifcopenshell.file

ifc = ifcopenshell.open(...)

selector = Selector()
buildingelementproxies = selector.parse(ifc, ".IfcBuildingElementProxy")
spaces = selector.parse(ifc, ".IfcSpace")
containedrelation = selector.parse(ifc, ".IfcRelContainedInSpatialStructure")
print (containedrelation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to get all proxies together with the spatial structure (e.g. storey) they are contained in, you have 3 options.

1. Start from relations as suggested in your question.

```python
for relation in containedrelation:
    for element in relation.RelatedElements:
        if element in buildingelementproxies:
            print(element.Name, "in", relation.RelatingStructure.Name)
```

2. Start from elements.

```python
for element in buildingelementproxies:
    for relation in element.ContainedInStructure:
        print(element.Name, "in", relation.RelatingStructure.Name)
```

3. Start from structures.

```python
spatialstructures = selector.parse(ifc, ".IfcSpatialStructureElement")
for structure in spatialstructures:
    for relation in structure.ContainsElements:
        for element in relation.RelatedElements:
            if element in buildingelementproxies:
                print(element.Name, "in", structure.Name)
```

Similarly you can use list comprehension to get the pairs of element and spatial structure.

```python
[(element.Name, relation.RelatingStructure.Name) for relation in containedrelation for element in relation.RelatedElements if element in buildingelementproxies]
[(element.Name, relation.RelatingStructure.Name) for element in buildingelementproxies for relation in element.ContainedInStructure]
[(element.Name, structure.Name) for structure in spatialstructures for relation in structure.ContainsElements for element in relation.RelatedElements if element in buildingelementproxies]
```